# Creating tables in MySQL in Python 3.4

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I am running a server through Apache using Python 3.4 as a cgi and a MySQL database server on Windows 10. When I try to run my function for creating the database I get the error:

```
DatabaseError: 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `testdb`.`studentexam` (errno: 150 
"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

The function for creating the database

```
import mysql.connector as conn

#connect to server
db=conn.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="")
cursor=db.cursor()
#create database
cursor.execute("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Testdb""")
db.commit()
#use database
cursor.execute("""USE Testdb""")
db.commit()
#create Teacher table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teacher(
    TeacherUsername VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    TeacherPassword TEXT)""")
db.commit()
#create student table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(
    StudentNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
    StudentSurname TEXT,
    StudentForename TEXT,
    StudentTeacher VARCHAR(255),
    StudentPassword TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentTeacher) REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherUsername))""")
db.commit()
#create exam table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Exam(
    TestName VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    TestTotalMarks TEXT,
    Teacher VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY(Teacher) REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherUsername))""")
db.commit()
#create StudentExam table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentExam(
    TestName VARCHAR(255),
    StudentID INT,
    StudentTotalMarks INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(TestName,StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TestName) REFERENCES Exam(TestName),
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID))""")
db.commit()
#create ExamSection table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ExamSection(
    TestName VARCHAR(255),
    SectionID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(TestName,SectionID),
    FOREIGN KEY(TestName) REFERENCES Exam(TestName),
    FOREIGN KEY(SectionID) REFERENCES Section(SectionID))""")
db.commit()
#create Section table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Section(
    SectionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SectionName TEXT,
    SectionTotalMarks INT)""")
db.commit()
#create Question table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Question(
    QuestionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SectionID VARCHAR(255),
    Image TEXT,
    Question TEXT,
    PossibleAnswer TEXT,
    CorrectAnswer TEXT,
    QuestionType TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(SectionID) REFERENCES Section(SectionID))""")
db.commit()
#create QuestionResults Table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS QuestionResults(
    QuestionID INT,
    StudentID INT,
    SectionID VARCHAR(255),
    StudentAnswer TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(QuestionID,StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY(QuestionID) REFERENCES Question(QuestionID)
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID))""")
db.commit()
#create Revision table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Revision(
    RevisionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    RevisionSheet TEXT,
    TeacherUsername VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY(TeacherUsername) REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherUsername))""")
db.commit()
#create StudentRevition table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentRevision(
    RevisionID INT,
    StudentID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(RevisionID,StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY(RevisionID) REFERENCES Revision(RevisionID),
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID))""")
db.commit()
#create StudentResults table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentResults(
    SectionID VARCHAR(255),
    StudentID INT,
    StudentSectionMarks INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(SectionID,StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY(SectionID) REFERENCES Section(SectionID),
    FOREIGN KEY(StudentID) REFERENCES Student(StudentID))""")
db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

EDIT: I Changed StudentNo to StudentID and now get the error:

```
DatabaseError: 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `testdb`.`examsection` (errno: 150
"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Your code is quite messy, it's difficult to find out. Try to collect all the SQL statements in a file `.sql` and run it from the `psql` command line by typing `\i name_file.sql`. Probably you will have more control and better error introspection. By the way the error is in the SQL not in the Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating StudentExam, you are referencing Student.StudentId which doesn't exist. It looks like you rather want to reference Student.StudentNo.

edit:

When you create ExamSection, you reference the Section table, which doesn't exist yet. Move the Section creation state up so that it runs and commits before you create ExamSection.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
#create student table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(
StudentNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentSurname TEXT,
StudentForename TEXT,
StudentTeacher VARCHAR(255),
StudentPassword TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(StudentTeacher) REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherUsername))""")
db.commit()
```

to this:

```
#create student table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student(
StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
StudentSurname TEXT,
StudentForename TEXT,
StudentTeacher VARCHAR(255),
StudentPassword TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(StudentTeacher) REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherUsername))""")
db.commit()
```